# Appending an owner to an item (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm very new to Django, so it may be a very simple answer, but I'm essentially making an ebay type website with Django.

I can create items, but I'm trying to get the owner to be on the item. Here's the model for the item:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    size = models.IntegerField()
    original_price = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="img")
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="items", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I've been told I now need to append the owner to the item, but I'm struggling to understand how or where.
I assume this is on the views.py file of the app, but fiddling around with it has proved unsuccessful.
Here's my view:

```
def create_item(request):   
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewItemForm(request.POST)
        owner = request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            item = form.save()
            return redirect(get_items)
    else:
        form = NewItemForm()
    return render(request, 'newitemform.html', {'form' : form})
```

I figured it would be item.append(owner) underneath item = form.save(), but that didn't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost made it!

Your `Item` entity already has an `owner` attribute of type `UserProfile`, so you just need to set this attr.

Try this code:

```
item = form.save(commit=False)
item.owner = owner
item.save()
```

Comment: Gah so close! Thank you so much for helping! It's working!

Answer (score 2):

You can do `form.save(commit=False)` to create an item object without actually saving it, then add `item.owner = owner`

```
def create_item(request):   
if request.method == "POST":
    form = NewItemForm(request.POST)
    owner = request.user
    if form.is_valid():
        item = form.save(commit=False)
        item.owner = owner
        item.save()
        return redirect(get_items)
else:
    form = NewItemForm()
return render(request, 'newitemform.html', {'form' : form})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response, all working now!